# Responsive image max height 100% doesnt work in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, responsive-design

i'm currently trying to make an image resize depending on the browser dimensions. I've managed to get the image to resize horizontally, if I make the browser window narrow the image will resize proportionally just fine. However when I resize the window vertically, Firefox just doesn't seem to want to do it! The code is pretty simple

```
<body>

    <div id="content">
        <img src="images/abc.jpg">
    </div>      

</body>
```

and the CSS:

```
#content {  
    height: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
}


#content img{
    max-height:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Another issue is that the image *does* seem to resize vertically in chrome, but i have to drag the bottom of the browser well over the image before it start doing this. I'd rather the image start to rezise as soon as the bottom content padding "hits" the bottom of the image so to speak. Hope this is making sense.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Can you provide an image sample? Which dimensions does `abc.jpg` have?

Comment: I think the height of #content probably will be more than 100% since you using padding. Basically, it adds 50+50 from top and bottom !!! To check, you can try giving a specific height to body

Comment: Ok, abc.jpg is big. so that you can see as much detail on whatever screen you're seeing it on. Say 1500 x 1000 px

Comment: @huMpty duMpty, having a set height doesn't seem to work sorry

Comment: @bestfriendsforever: I didn't wanted to say that setting the height going to work!!! I just gave you the idea :)

Answer (score 2):

try this, taken from Twitter bootstrap 2

```
html,body{height:100%;}
#content {padding: 5%;}
#content img {
max-height: 100%;/* Part 1: Set a maxium relative to the parent */
width: auto\9;
/* IE7-8 need help adjusting responsive images */
max-width: auto; 
/* Part 2: Scale the height according to the width, otherwise you get stretching */
vertical-align: middle;
border: 0;
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because height could potentially go on forever, you cant set the height of anything relative to the browser window to be a function of percent. What i'm saying is that you will need to put it inside of something with a fixed height to use a per-cent value. Good Luck!

-b

Comment: Ok, thanks. Although that defeats the purpose of this image as i'd like it to resize to the height as well as the browser so that you can resize the browser to kind of "zoom" in. seems to be working fine on [this website](http://www.olivierhess.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You've only specified the "max-height" and "max-width" properties.
If you don't specify the actual "width" or "height" properties, the image initialy takes the width and height of its physical dimensions (if not larger than the specified max-height and max-width).

Said that, the behaviour you've noticed, is correct.
The answer is, as already mentioned, to specify also a initial width or height property, dependig wether your image is portrait or landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Is [that](http://jsfiddle.net/nk9cU/) what you want?

I actually just added a height to html and body, so that #contents height doesn't get to high.

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

(And box-sizing: border-box to #content, because it seems like you'd want that)